# iCloud Debug Gauge Status: Disabled

Tags: ios, debugging, ios8, xcode6, icloud

I created an app, testing Core Data Sync with iCloud. The app works, data syncs between devices without issues.

When debugging, running on device from Xcode (6) the iCloud Debug Gauge says Status: Disabled. I do not see my containers and files in the list below. Occasionally, the graph shows some downloading but nothing else seems to report.

I do get the expected messages and logs output in the debug console and, as I said, the devices are syncing. Objects added on one device propagate to the other, deletes and updates all work fine.

Why does the gauge say disabled and why am I not seeing the debug information? Is there something I need to do to enable the debug gauge in Xcode?

[image: Xcode Debug Gauge Screenshot]

Comment: The iCloud gauge is broken in ios8 / Xcode 6 / iCloud drive (one of the above). There are a few threads about it on the apple dev forums.

Comment: Is that right, thanks. I have been googling for hours and could barely find a single thing specifically about the gauge. I should have went to the forums directly.

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1026708#1026708 is the one I found when I had this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iCloud gauge is currently broken in Xcode 6.  Be sure to file a bug with Apple so they fix it.

There's an Apple forum thread on it here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1026708#1026708

Comment: hahahahahaha! What is exactly working well on Xcode? This bug has one year.